# jquery does not change the attribute although javascript does

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery

I am trying to change the attribute of a span. jquery does not change the value but javascript does. What can be the problem? Is there any disadvantage of using javascript?

My code is as follows:

```
$('#ctl00_c_ActivityContainer_ctl00_ctl01_tmmQuestionZone_0').attr('draggable', 'false');               
document.getElementById("ctl00_c_ActivityContainer_ctl00_ctl01_tmmQuestionZone_0").setAttribute("draggable", "false");

<span id="ctl00_c_ActivityContainer_ctl00_ctl01_tmmQuestionZone_0" draggable="true">
</span>
```

Comment: Actually it works well for me. Check this sample in jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/VZSJ9/1/ . Also, on what browser are you testing it? do you see any error message on the javascript console?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use [prop](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) method ( assumes jQuery >=1.6)

```
$('#ctl00_c_ActivityContainer_ctl00_ctl01_tmmQuestionZone_0').prop('draggable', false);
```

Also you were using a string for "false'